# Messages not passing correctly between Chrome extension background pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to break up the background script of a Chrome extension into smaller, more manageable individual scripts that communicate with each other via message passing. Right now I have two scripts `background.js` and `database.js`.

background.js

```
var message = 1;
console.log("Background.js running");
console.log("Sending message " + message);
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message, function (response) {
    console.log("Response received " + response);
    message+=1;
})
```

database.js

```
console.log("Database.js running");
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, requester, sendResponse) 
{
    console.log("message received " + request);
    console.log("Sending response " + request);
    sendResponse(request);
    return true;
});
```

They both run on startup and `database.js` registers a message listener.I then use sendMessage in `database.js`, hoping to receive and handle it in `database.js`. However, the callback for sending the message is called immediately, with an empty response, and the handler in `database.js` does not trigger.

When I run the extension with the above two scripts, I would like to see the output:

```
Database.js running
Background.js running
Sending message 1
Message received 1
Sending response 1
Response received 1
```

I instead get:

```
Database.js running
Background.js running
Sending message 1
Response received undefined
```

What causes this behavior and is it fixable?

Comment: Perhaps you should post a [MCVE] of this.

Comment: Why message passing with the same context instead of just calling functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage):

> If sending to your extension, the runtime.onMessage event will be
>   fired in every frame of your extension (**except for the sender's frame**)

You can't receive a message in the same frame/context it is sent. Like Daniel Herr pointed out, you can just call the functions you want instead of passing messages.

Comment: Thank you, I misunderstood how the architecture worked. I thought that different background scripts were more isolated than they actually are.